# User clicks on other product to remove but by default it is removing the last product from the cart In Ionic Ecommerce App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3

I am working on the Ionic Ecommerce App and I have added the products to the cart and I have also the added the remove button for the products but the problem is that when I am clicking on any product to remove it is always removing the last product from the cart.

This is my **cart.html**:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Your Cart</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let itm of cartItems" class="myitem11">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img src="{{itm.image}}">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2>{{itm.name}}</h2>
      <p>
        Actual Price:
        <span [ngStyle]="itm?.discountp === '0' ? {'text-decoration':'none'} : {'text-decoration':'line-through'}">₹{{itm.disprice
          * itm.count}}</span>
      </p>
      <p>Discount: {{itm?.discountp}}%</p>
      <p>Size: {{itm?.psize}}</p>
      <ion-row class="item-count">
        <ion-col class="qty">
          <button (click)="decreaseProductCount(itm)" clear ion-button small color="dark" class="mewbtn11">
            -
          </button>
          <button ion-button small clear color="dark" class="mewbtn11">
            {{itm?.count}}
          </button>
          <button (click)="incrementProductCount(itm)" clear ion-button small color="dark" class="mewbtn11">
            +
          </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <p>
        Discounted Price: ₹{{itm.productPrice * itm.count}}
      </p>
      <button ion-button icon-only clear item-end (click)="removeItem(itm)">
        <ion-icon class="mycaicon11" name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="single-footer" ngif="!isEmptyCart">

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="addCart" (click)="checkpage()">
        <button color="secondary" full ion-button round="true">
          {{totalAmount}} Checkout
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

</ion-footer>
```

In this cart view, I have shown the remove button.

This is my **cart.ts**:

```
import { CheckoutPage } from './../checkout/checkout';
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CartProvider } from "../../providers/cart/cart";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-cart',
  templateUrl: 'cart.html',
})
export class CartPage {
 cartItems: any[] = [];
 totalAmount: number = 0;
 isCartItemLoaded: boolean = false;
 isEmptyCart: boolean = true;
 productCount: number = 1;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private cartService: CartProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad CartPage');
    this.cartService.getCartItems().then((val) => {
      this.cartItems = val;
      console.log(val);
    });
    this.loadCartItems();
  }

  loadCartItems() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Wait.."
    });
    loader.present();
    this.cartService
      .getCartItems()
      .then(val => {
        this.cartItems = val;
        if (this.cartItems.length > 0) {
          this.cartItems.forEach((v, indx) => {
            this.totalAmount += parseInt(v.totalPrice);
            console.log(this.totalAmount);
          });
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          this.isEmptyCart = false;
        }

        this.isCartItemLoaded = true;
        loader.dismiss();
      })
      .catch(err => {});
  }

  removeItem(itm) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Remove Product',
      message: 'Do you want to remove this product?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel Clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Yes',
          handler: () => {
            this.cartService.removeFromCart(itm).then(() => {
              this.loadCartItems();
            });
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }

  checkpage()
  {
    this.navCtrl.push(CheckoutPage);
  }

  decreaseProductCount(itm) {
    if (itm.count > 1) {
      itm.count--;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }

  incrementProductCount(itm) {
    itm.count++;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

In this ts file, I have the remove function: removeItem(itm).

This is my **Cart Service:** **Providers>Cart>cart.ts**:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

const CART_KEY = 'cartItems';

@Injectable()
export class CartProvider {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) {
    console.log('Hello CartProvider Provider');
  }

  addToCart(productdet) {
    return this.getCartItems().then(result => {
      if (result) {
        if (!this.containsObject(productdet, result)) {
          result.push(productdet);
          return this.storage.set(CART_KEY, result);
        } else {
          let index = result.findIndex(x => x.product_id == productdet.product_id);
          let prevQuantity = parseInt(result[index].count);
          productdet.count = (prevQuantity + productdet.count);
          let currentPrice = (parseInt(productdet.totalPrice));
          productdet.totalPrice = currentPrice;
          result.splice(index, 1);
          result.push(productdet);
          return this.storage.set(CART_KEY, result);
        }

      } else {
        return this.storage.set(CART_KEY, [productdet]);
      }
    })
  }

  removeFromCart(productdet) {
    return this.getCartItems().then(result => {
      if (result) {
        var productIndex = result.indexOf(productdet);
        result.splice(productIndex, 1);
        return this.storage.set(CART_KEY, result);
      }
    })
  }

  removeAllCartItems() {
    return this.storage.remove(CART_KEY).then(res => {
      return res;
    });
  }


  containsObject(obj, list): boolean {
    if (!list.length) {
      return false;
    }

    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      if (list[i].product_id == obj.product_id) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  getCartItems() {
    return this.storage.get(CART_KEY);
  }
}
```

The problem is that I have added the products to the cart but when I am clicking on the remove button in the cart it is always removing the last product in the cart. It should remove the product on which we have clicked. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes sense when reading your code. The problem lays in your removeFromCart function where you create a new list of items and then try to find the index of the item to be removed in a newly created array that has other objects in it with new references.

Try something like this :

```
removeFromCart(productdet) {
    return this.getCartItems().then(result => {
      if (result && result.length) {
        const newList = result.filter(el => el.id !== productdet.id);
        return this.storage.set(CART_KEY, newList);
      }
    })
  }
```

provided that you have unique Id properties to distinguish between your products

Comment: productdet contains unique product_id, (el => el.product_id !== productdet.product_id);

Comment: Can you please help me with my other question.

Comment: what other question ?